# Photoshop Javascript encoding error

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

My Code:

```
// _name = mz15_09
var _num = _name.slice(2,7)
var _yr ="20"+ _name.slice(2,4)
var _mon = _name.slice(5,7)

_layerpath = "/Volumes/sv_ebv/Werbung/Hefte\ 3D/"+_yr+"/"+_num+"/\*Daten\ für\ EBV\ _EBENEN /";
    _savepath = "/Volumes/sv_ebv/Werbung/Hefte\ 3D/"+_yr+"/"+_num;
    _x1 = _layerpath+"Heft_MZ"+_num+"_CH_R05.psd"
    var fileRef1 = new File(_x1)
    app.open (fileRef1)
```

(app.open) should open the given File but Photoshop denies to do so.
I used the debugging console in my ESTK and this it what it says:

```
_x1
Ergebnis: /Volumes/sv_ebv/Werbung/Hefte 3D/2015/15_09/*Daten für EBV _EBENEN /Heft_MZ15_09_CH_R05.psd

fileRef1
Ergebnis: /sv_ebv/Werbung/Hefte%203D/2015/15_09/*Daten%20fu%CC%88r%20EBV%20_EBENEN%20/Heft_MZ15_09_CH_R05.psd
```

my path ist valid (even with all those vars in it) but after i put it in the new File() command, the encoding crashes. How do I fix this? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid folder name `*Daten für EBV _EBENEN` 
if you remove `*` from it and space from the end, it might work

Comment: I see. It's not a proper folder name. This folder may be renamed, but I can't rename "Hefte 3D", which has also a space...

Comment: It can have spaces within name, but not in front and not in the end

Comment: thank you, I just removed the Space after _EBENEN in my Script and it works even the real folder keeps it...